# Distinct and orderby doctrine querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query that I need to get working:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ProjectPhaseUser');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
  ->select('(p2.project) AS projectId')
  ->leftJoin('AppBundle:ProjectPhase', 'p2', 'WITH', 'p.projectPhase = p2.id')
  ->where('p.user = ' . $user->getId())
  ->orderBy('p.assignDate', 'DESC')
  ->setMaxResults(3)
  ->getQuery();
```

Basically there are 2 tables: ProjectPhaseUser and ProjectPhase
What resides in the ProjectPhaseUser table are the users with projectphases and an assigndate. In the ProjectPhase table you have the projectphases and projects they belong to.

What I want is to get the 3 last assigned projects of a particular user.

What the query does now is get the last 3 projectphases their projects. However this gives me duplicate projects since a project can have multiple projectphases. When I try a distinct on the project I get the problem that orderby is not in the select clause. I also have tried groupby which gives me the only full group by mysql error.

How can I achieve this without altering the mysql only full group by option?

Comment: So the same project can have multiple assign dates (one for each project phase)? You may need to do `->addOrderBy('projectId')` and not limit to 3 results, then in your code look for first 3 unique projectId's.

Comment: Yes indeed. That what I was trying to avoid since I need to query for everything then and that can cost query time if there are a lot of records.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question: `How can I achieve this without altering the mysql only full group by option?`

Comment: Well when I search for this specific question, people suggest to change sql mode. I don't want that, I want a query that does work since the mode isn't there for nothing